# How can I easily and simply schedule a cron job in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, unix, cron

How can I easily and simply schedule a cron job in PHP? Rails has BackgroundRB...

Answer (score 2):

Most website control panels (assuming you've got cPanel or something similar running) include a crontab application. If you're on shared hosting ask your host about this.

If you're on a dedicated server and have installed cron then have a look at the [crontab syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#crontab_syntax). These commands go in `crontab`, usually in `/etc` on *nix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a semi-PHP solution to add to a crontab:

```
$cmd  = 'crontab -l > /tmp/crontab.bak'; // preserve current crontab
$cmd .= ' && echo "*/5 * * * * /foo/bar" >> /tmp/crontab.bak'; // append new command
$cmd .= ' && crontab /tmp/crontab.bak'; // update crontab
$cmd .= ' rm /tmp/crontab.bak'; // delete temp file

exec($cmd); // execute
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [PHP-Resque](http://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque), a PHP port of the queue&background process framework written by GitHub guys.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/

Comment: Good to note that phpJobScheduler is FREE to use its released under GPL License.

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating a language with a framework. PHP doesn't have a cron scheduling any more than Ruby does. If you're using a PHP framework or cms however, there is likely some utility for cron tasks.

Here is a useful link if you have control over the machine. 
[http://troy.jdmz.net/cron/](http://troy.jdmz.net/cron)
If you have shared hosting, there's probably some tool they'd give you for cron jobs; ask them or look in the knowledge base.