# Sending Mail automatically at a particular time?

Tags: php

I am going to add one module to my project this module is about remainders.If today's date is a birthday of a person then a mail must be send to that person automatically at 9.00 A.M

Comment: Windows or Linux server?

Comment: I think you should following this question [How can I easily and simply schedule a cron job in PHP?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448132/how-can-i-easily-and-simply-schedule-a-cron-job-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send mail to different customer on their birthday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494057/send-mail-to-different-customer-on-their-birthday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If your xampp is on Windows, you can use [windows-schedulers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to call a
>      particular script (PHP script in your case, preferably by an URL),
>      which checks the birthdays of all the users and sends them mail
>      accordingly.
> 2. If your xampp is on Linux/Unix/etc, you can use [cron-jobs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/),
>      and rest is same!
> 3. There is also a third way, a third-party scheduler or say [online-cron](http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/), which will remotely
>      call yours script (php-page).
>
> **Example:**
>
> If you are doing the cron-settings of OS yourself, you can still let
>   the configure as to whom to email in your system, rather than OS.
>
> After all, a cron so is to do something repeatedly, in your case, its
>   just calling your scripts, by an URL.
>
> Now regarding the time settings, you can make the CRON call your
>   script every our, and you php script will check the appropriate time,
>   and fire the mails!

**Reference:** [Send mail to different customer on their birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494057/send-mail-to-different-customer-on-their-birthday)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

You could always add a cron job/scheduled task that runs at 9 am and hits a service that checks if any mail needs to be sent out that day.